# Como puedo hacer para sacar los decimales?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy utilizando los datatables de jquery y tambien uso bootstrap4. En las columnas de tipo number me aparecen con decimales pero necesito sacarlos y no se como.

Les muestro una imagen de como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Serían las columnas Costo Fob y Precio de Lista donde no necesito los decimales.

Esta seria la etiqueta de Costo fob pero solamente la parte del titulo.

```
<th class="quitarDecimales sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 69px;" aria-label="Costo Fob: activate to sort column ascending">Costo Fob</th>
```

No se como identificar a todos los valores de la columna y poder quitarles los decimales

Y esta es mi vista donde se encuentra el datatable:

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
                        <thead class="thead">

                            

                            <tr>
                                <th style="display: none">Codigo</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Tipo de Producto</th>
                                <th>Marca</th>
                                <th>Modelo</th>
                                <th>Moneda de Compra</th>                                                                       
                                <th class="quitarDecimales">Costo Fob</th>
                                <th>Moneda de Venta</th>
                                <th class="quitarDecimales">Precio de Lista</th>
                                <th>Margen Bruto</th>
                                
                                <th style="width: 12%">Accion</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           
                            @foreach($file as $key => $product)
                            @if($product->status == 1)
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product['ptype']['productType']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->coin }}</td>                                    
                                    <td>{{ $product->costUSD }}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->sale_coin}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->list_priceUSD}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->marginUSD}}</td>
                                    
                                    @php
                                    $count_product = App\Model\Purchase::where('product_id',$product->id)->count();
                                    @endphp
                                        <td>


                                        <!--<a title="Download" id="download" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                                            href="/products/download/{{ $product->file }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-download"></i></a>-->
                                        <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white"
                                            style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);"
                                            href="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                            href="{{ route('products.delete', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                        <a title="Info" id="info" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{{route('products.detail', $product->id)}}" ><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></a>
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif

                                
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                        
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /.card-body -->
```

Comment: muestra el código con el que llenas tu tabla, de otra forma no podrán ayudarte.

Comment: Procura crar un [mre] suficiente para al menos, replicar el error. No estás , mostrando casi nada del código.

Comment: Editada @valle50

Comment: la clase `quitarDecimales` que hace?? Como llegan los valores que terminan con decimales??

Comment: @Excorpion no hace nada todavia la agregue para tratar de identificar a la columna que tiene numeros y no texto. Los valores llegan mediante un formulario y guarda los datos con metodos de un controlador en laravel-7

Answer (score 2):

Puedes convertir el valor a entero desde PHP con la función [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php)

```
                                <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{$product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $product['ptype']['productType']}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $product->coin }}</td>                                    
                                <td>{{ intval($product->costUSD) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $product->sale_coin }}</td>
                                <td>{{ intval($product->list_priceUSD) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $product->marginUSD }}</td>
```

Comment: esa tabulación Triby

Comment: @Excorpion, resultado de copiar y pegar. :-)